# Is it possible to use pointfree expressions in signature facts?

Tags: alloy

Suppose we have the following alloy model:

```
sig A {}

sig B  {
  R : A
  } 

fact {
  R.~R in iden
  }

run {}
```

On executing run, alloy finds an instance.  I thought I'd try to change the model's fact into a *signature fact*, as below:

```
sig A {}

sig B  {
  R : A
    } {
    R.~R in iden
    }

run {}
```

but when I do, alloy tells me:

```
A type error has occurred:
~ can be used only with a binary relation.
Instead, its possible type(s) are:
{this/A}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement the already given answer, yes it is possible.

You can use the @ operator.

```
sig A {}

sig B  {
  R : A
    } {
    @R.~@R in iden
    }

run {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the signature R is treated as of type A, not B->A.

But this fact belongs outside the signature as it is about the global structure of R, not the local piece of R, b.R, for each b:B.

If you had a second relation in B, say S:A, you could have signature facts such as R != S that translate to b.R != b.S, for each b:B.